# How to use String replace correctly in this case?

Tags: java

I have got a SMS Template as shown below

**User: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Ph: XXXXXXXXXX, Loc: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Area: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, added you for Home Delivery. Please review details**

where XXXXXX needs to be filled with dynamic values

I have tried this way as shown below

but when i run the program the output i am getting is

```
User: Kiran, Ph: 11111111111111, Loc: KiranXX, Area: KiranXX, added you for Home Delivery. Please review details
```

It is adding XX to the end 
This is my program

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException
    {

        String user = "Kiran";
        String phone = "11111111111111";
        String loc = "my location";
        String area = "my area";


        String message = "User: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Ph: XXXXXXXXXX, Loc: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Area: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, added you for Home Delivery. Please review details\r\n" + 
                "";

        message = message.replace("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", user);
        message = message.replace("XXXXXXXXXX", phone);
        message = message.replace("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", loc);
        message = message.replace("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", area);

        System.out.println(message);


    }

}
```

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: Why on earth are you using Xs for this?

Comment: that was the template i have been given , i know i should use {user_name} regular expressions , but i am helpless

Comment: Look into `String.format`

Comment: Template you've been given by whom? Why can't you just change it, or tell them to provide something less transparently stupid? Unless you replace everything in length order this won't work, and what if two are the same length?

Comment: For God sake, couldn't you change those X into variables linke {user_name} as you say???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use this:

```
String template = "User: %s, Ph: %s, Loc: %s, Area: %s, added you for Home Delivery. Please review details\r\n";

String result = String.format(template, user, phone, loc, area);
```

[Javadoc of String.format() here](http://goo.gl/hPRzOn)

Answer (score 1):

First replace is definately wrong.

I WILL code like this:

**Edit:**

```
message = message.replace("User: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "User: " +user);
```

Comment: Firstly, can you explain why you'd do that? Secondly, what happened to the space after the colon?

Comment: yes, you have ommited an space after the colon. Moreover, I would put a \\s+ which means "at least one whitespace character" which is more flexible

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```
message = message.replace( "User:\\s+X+", "User: " + user );
```

This will:

- ignore how many spaces there are after the User: and the X's
- ignore how many X's are there, just eat everyone of them